# Discord.NET: Bot not processing input

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to make a "warning" command for a bot which takes a SocketGuildUser parameter, adds 1 to a warning int. However, when I try to enter a user @mention for SocketGuildUser, which should work, an exception is thrown.

```
[Command("warn")]
    public async Task WarnUser(SocketGuildUser user)
    {
        string warningDirectory = @"D:\HumbleBot\HumbleBot\Warnings";
        string warningText = @"D:\HumbleBot\HumbleBot\Warnings\warnings.json";

        if (!Directory.Exists(warningDirectory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(warningDirectory);

        Dictionary<ulong, uint> UserWarnings = new Dictionary<ulong, uint>();
        UserWarnings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
                       <Dictionary<ulong, uint>>
                       (File.ReadAllText(warningText));

        if (!UserWarnings.ContainsKey(id)) //Exception thrown here
            UserWarnings.Add(id, 0);

        UserWarnings.TryGetValue(id, out uint warningNum);
        UserWarnings[id] = warningNum++;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UserWarnings);
        File.WriteAllText(warningText, json);
        //builder
    }
```

Input: ~warn @Stratus#6727
Output (in Console): Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

EDIT: Added the rest of the code; as it turns out it has something to do with that and not what I'd added. It probably has something to do with the file reading/writing, or I'm using JsonConvert the wrong way.

Comment: Hard to tell from just your snippet what the problem is. It does seem that you are facing a classic case of "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" though.

Comment: I can post the rest of the method, if that would help. I did leave out some file read/write lines.

Comment: If you are using visual studio, you can set up the debugger to stop when an exception is thrown. This will tell you exactly which line of code is the problem. Currently we don't know which line is failing.

Comment: I see. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the parameter SocketGuildUser is a little picky. You might want to try this:

```
public async Task WarnPlayer(SocketUser u)
{
    SocketGuildUser user = (SocketGuildUser)u;
```

Answer (score 0):

in my SLN the SocketUser works fine, maybe you should catch it too if no user was tagged (added it for you with the default value)

```
    [Command("warn")]
    public async Task WarnPlayer(SocketUser user = null)
    {
        if (user != null)
        {

        Dictionary<string, uint> PlayerWarnings = JsonConvert
            .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, uint>>(File.ReadAllText(warningText));

        PlayerWarnings.Add(user.Username, 1);

        PlayerWarnings.TryGetValue(user.Username, out uint warningNum);

        EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();

        builder.WithDescription
                ($"{user.Username} has been given a warning. They now have {warningNum}")
            .WithColor(Color.Gold)
            .WithThumbnailUrl(user.GetAvatarUrl());

        await ReplyAsync("", false, builder.Build());
        }
        else
        {
            EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();

            builder.WithDescription
                    ($"Please select a user to warn.")
                .WithColor(Color.Red)
                .WithThumbnailUrl(user.GetAvatarUrl());

            await ReplyAsync("", false, builder.Build());
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Maybe you also want to change the `user.Username` to a `user.DiscordId` because I think the Username can be changed.